# How to get multiple instances of a class (in different threads) to listen to the same event?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I'm new to event handling and threading in C#, so forgive me if this question is basic: How do I create several classes to run on different threads, all listening for the same event?

For example, I receive a new piece of data frequently but at random intervals. When this data arrives I update a class with the new data, let's call it `MyDataClass`, which raises an event: `MyDataClass.NewEvent`.

Then I have a class called `NewEventHandler`. When an event fires, this class does some calculation with the new data, then sends the result to another application.

So the problem is this:
I need to have around 30 instances of `NewEventHandler` all listening to `MyDataClass.NewEvent` (each does the different calculation and produces a different result). It's important that these calculations all run simultaneously - as soon as the event fires all 30 instances of `NewEventHandler` start calculating. However, it does not matter if they finish together or not (e.g. there's no synchronization needed here).

How do I actually create the instances of `NewEventHandler` so that they run on different threads, and get them to all listen to a single instance of `MyDataClass.NewEvent`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple threads waiting on one event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416270/multiple-threads-waiting-on-one-event)

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but I like the abstract nature of this question.  "Multilple threads waiting on one event?" reads concretely of that OP domain problem.  I hope this question gets answered on its own.

Comment: @Eric the questions are different - this one is about handing C# style events (delegates), the suggested one is about blocking synchronization on an OS event.

Comment: Note that instances of classes don't "run on different threads", they don't run at all. Only particular methods (or even part of a method in case of `async`/`await` code) can be said "runs on a thread".

Comment: I would point out that events (as the question poses it) are in fact a delegate that is invoked on the same thread that it is fired on, so another thread doesn't really listen for an event.  The simplest approach would be to set up a ManualResetEvent instead of firing a C# event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, the general practice is that the event listener's methods are called on the same thread which fires the event. The standard template to fire an event from the source class is:

```
void FireNewEvent() 
{
     var tmp = NewEvent;
     if( tmp != null )
     { 
         tmp(this, YourEventArgsInstance);
     }
}
```

Event is not much but a little glorified delegate. So this call is similar to a multicast delegate call - meaning all the subscribers will be called sequentially on the same thread the `FireNewEvent` is running from. I suggest you do not change this behavior.

If you want to run event subscribers simultaneously then  you start a new task in each subscriber.

```
...
MyDataClass.NewEvent += OneOfSubscriberClassInstance.OnNewEvent;

...
public void OnNewEvent(object sender, YourEventArgs args)
{ 
   Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {

       // all your event handling code here 
   });
}
```

Code which fires event will fire 30 subscribers sequentially, but each subscriber will run in its own thread scheduled by TPL. So, delegate which fires event will not have to wait to fire the next subscriber's handler until currently called subscriber's handler has finished handling the event.

Comment: +1 It looks like the MyDataClass should have some method (for the task) which starts a new thread.

Comment: Thanks - I had not seen the task library before, this looks like it does the job well! Poses a whole set of new questions, but for anyone reading this with the same problem, the [MSDN page on Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) looks verbose and easy to follow

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example/demonstration of how you can synchronize the different threads and ensure they all respond to events at the same time. You can copy and paste this code into a console application to see it run.

```
public class Program
{
    private static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle;
    private const int ThreadCount = 20;
    private static int _signalledCount = 0;
    private static int _invokedCount = 0;
    private static int _eventCapturedCount = 0;
    private static CountdownEvent _startCounter;
    private static CountdownEvent _invokeCounter;
    private static CountdownEvent _eventCaptured;


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
        _startCounter = new CountdownEvent(ThreadCount);
        _invokeCounter = new CountdownEvent(ThreadCount);
        _eventCaptured = new CountdownEvent(ThreadCount);

        //Start multiple threads that block until signalled
        for (int i = 1; i <= ThreadCount; i++)
        {
            var t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadProc));
            t.Start(i);
        }

        //Allow all threads to start
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        _startCounter.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to allow waiting threads to proceed.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        //Signal threads to start
        _waitHandle.Set();

        //Wait for all threads to acknowledge start
        _invokeCounter.Wait();

        //Signal threads to proceed
        _waitHandle.Reset();

        Console.WriteLine("All threads ready. Raising event.");

        var me = new object();

        //Raise the event
        MyEvent(me, new EventArgs());

        //Wait for all threads to capture event
        _eventCaptured.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1} threads responded to event.", _eventCapturedCount, ThreadCount);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static EventHandler MyEvent;

    public static void ThreadProc(object index)
    {
        //Signal main thread that this thread has started
        _startCounter.Signal();
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _signalledCount);

        //Subscribe to event
        MyEvent += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} responded to event.", index);
            _eventCaptured.Signal();
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _eventCapturedCount);
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} blocks.", index);

        //Wait for main thread to signal ok to start
        _waitHandle.WaitOne();

        //Signal main thread that this thread has been invoked
        _invokeCounter.Signal();
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _invokedCount);
    }
}
```